# Android Application isn't installed after deployment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation

I've developed an application using Eclipse and when I run it on my Droid Ultra the application runs when running through Eclipse. To my understanding when that happens the application should be installed on the device.  However, when I unplug the device and try to run the app by going through my phone applications it displays a toast message saying "App isn't installed". Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this a code problem, an environment issue, anything?

Here is my manifest if it helps?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.ggc.thinkfast"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.BLUETOOTH">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FactScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:noHistory="true"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".CategoryScreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".TimerScreen"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:noHistory="true"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".QuestionScreen"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          android:noHistory="true"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".NextQuestionScreen"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:noHistory="true"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you check off the setting that allows you to run applications from Unknown Sources?

Comment: That option is checked. Should it be checked off?

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have the app installed previously on the device?If so please uninstall the existing app and try again with eclipse.The problem may be due to incorrectly signed certificates.